# Concatenate unique numpy arrays with counters

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, unique

Is there a simple yet efficient way to concatenate two unique numpy arrays which have counters?

### Example:

```py
values1 = np.array(['host1', 'host2', 'host3', 'host6'])
counts1 = np.array([2,5,2,4])

values2 = np.array(['host3', 'host1', 'host4'])
counts2 = np.array([5,7,1])
```

I'd like to have a result like:

```py
values_res = np.array(['host1', 'host2', 'host3', 'host6', 'host4'])
counts_res = np.array([9,5,7,4,1])
```

They do not need to be ordered, but `values_res` does need to be unique.

I could iterate over the elements in the array, but that would not be efficient. I'd like to use vectorization somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably faster (specially for larger arrays) and is ordered:

```
values_res, idx = np.unique(np.hstack((values1, values2)), return_inverse=True)
counts_res = np.bincount(idx, np.hstack((counts1, counts2)))
```

output:

```
['host1' 'host2' 'host3' 'host4' 'host6']
[9. 5. 7. 1. 4.]
```

---

**Comparison** using benchit:

```
#@Ehsan's solution
def m1(values1, values2, counts1, counts2):
  values_res, idx = np.unique(np.hstack((values1, values2)), return_inverse=True)
  counts_res = np.bincount(idx, np.hstack((counts1, counts2)))
  return values_res, counts_res

#@Chris's solution
def m2(values1, values2, counts1, counts2):

  values_res, counts_res = zip(*dict(Counter(dict(zip(values1,counts1))) + Counter(dict(zip(values2,counts2)))).items())
  return values_res, counts_res


in_ = {n:[np.random.choice(values_res, n), np.random.choice(values_res, n), np.random.randint(1,100,n), np.random.randint(1,100,n)] for n in [10,100,1000,10000]}
```

output:

**m1** is faster in this setting

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could leverage the fact that Counters can be added together.  Zip each pair, make a counter, add them together, then unpack.

```
from collections import Counter

values1 = np.array(['host1', 'host2', 'host3'])
counts1 = np.array([2,5,2])

values2 = np.array(['host3', 'host1', 'host4'])
counts2 = np.array([5,7,1])


values_res, counts_res = zip(*dict(Counter(dict(zip(values1,counts1))) + Counter(dict(zip(values2,counts2)))).items())
```

Comment: Does the work. Thanks. I'll wait for some more answers just in case there are other options which can outperform this approach.